# CentOS: disable a non-reachable repository

Tags: centos, yum, repository

**How to disable a non-reachable repository?**

I have an error when I use `yum repolist` or `yum list`:

```
# yum list | grep 404
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home%3A/SannisDev/
CentOS_CentOS-    5/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
```

And indeed the url is not reachable:

```
# ping opensuse.org
PING opensuse.org (130.57.5.70) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.2.15.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

But I can't find the repository in `/etc/yum.conf`:

```
# grep opensuse /etc/*
```

Comment: Uhm... wait a second, getting a `404` *HTTP Return Code* means there has been a HTTP connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to search that host using -R option in grep.

```
grep -R opensuse  /etc/yum.repos.d/ | cut -d":" -f1
```

above command will print the exact matching files.

and you can comment that links on the fly using :

```
grep -R opensuse  /etc/yum.repos.d/ | cut -d":" -f1 | xargs -n1 sed -i.bkp "/opensuse/ s/^/#/"
```

Comment: I had an error "Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo" so I comment all the file and the errors disapear